# apply an existed style for ListBoxItem template

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, wpf-controls, listboxitem

I'm trying to give a style to items in a `ListBox`, I made this style previously for ListViewItem which about TextBlock, Image and a Border which changes its color when an item  event raised (**IsSelected, IsMouseOver, IsSelectionActive**), Now I want to keep this style and apply it to any item added to a `ListBox`

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxPCInfoStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68">
                        <Image x:Name="Img" Width="56" Height="56" Margin="6,0,6,18" Source="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path= ActualHeight}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Height="17" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#33C1DEFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#41A5CDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7DA2CE"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7DA2CE"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#97C1DEFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A7A5CDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFB4B4B4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7FE5E5E5" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#B2CCCCCC" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And I have this ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListHosts" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Img" Source="BtnImg/Computer.png" Stretch="None" Margin="3,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PCName" Margin="0,7" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"><Run Text="{Binding Name}"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here... can someone help me spot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Options:

Either remove the `x:Key` from the style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <!-- ... -->
```

this will make the style apply to *all* `ListBoxItem`s in the resource scope.

or

Explicitly reference the style in your `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxPCInfoStyle}">
    <!-- ... -->
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Anyways, all your XAML is wrong. You're defining the `ListBoxItem.Template` like this:

```
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68">
                    <Image x:Name="Img" Width="56" Height="56" Margin="6,0,6,18" Source="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path= ActualHeight}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Height="17" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
                </Grid>
```

Which leaves no chance for custom `DataTemplates` to be introduced anywhere. You need to leave a `ContentPresenter` somewhere, so that WPF has a chance to put DataTemplated content inside that.

And the `TextBlock` makes no sense. You're binding against the `ListBoxItem.Name` property, which is completely irrelevant and makes no sense to be shown in the UI, and which you have no control over, anyways.

Data does not belong into `ControlTemplate`s, only `DataTemplate`s.

Change your template like so:

```
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68">
                    <Image x:Name="Img" Width="56" Height="56" Margin="6,0,6,18" Source="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path= ActualHeight}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/> 
                </Grid>
```

And the `ListBox` XAML is also wrong:

By doing this:

```
<ListBox ...>
  <DataTemplate>
      <!-- ... -->
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You're putting the `DataTemplate` as an item inside the ListBox, which is not what you want.
You need to specifically assign the `DataTemplate` as the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ...>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <!-- ... -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And why is the `Image.Source` bound to a property of type `double`? That makes no sense. 
Either put a specific resource there:

```
<Image Source="/resources/somepic.png"/>
```

or

if you want to dynamically change the image dependending on certain data, then that belongs into the `DataTemplate`, not the `ControlTemplate`.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I suggest you read up the following material:

- MSDN: [WPF Content Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/bb613548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- MSDN: [WPF Controls Content Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613556%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- Dr. WPF: [ItemsControls A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)